# How do I replicate google searches?

Tags: discussion, google

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38631/searching-in-google-with-a-questions-title-doesnt-make-the-question-appear-on-t), I was using LMGTFY to replicate a google search of stack overflow to replicate a problem I had. For [understandable reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35256/sorry-posts-cant-contain-that-content), LMGTFY is banned, but what should I use instead?

Bonus down-votes for those telling me to google for the answer.

Comment: Well... In that particular instance, I'm not sure what the point of the little LMGTFY animation would be. Might as well just link to the actual query, since it's the results that are relevant to the question itself.

Comment: @Shog9: Wouldn't I have to edit the URL from doing a search to remove the `&browser=lynx&SSN=078-05-1120` stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options/workarounds:

- Screencast yourself doing that search and post the video up on one of those video sharing websites
- [Freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) across a series of unanimated images between each step.
- Create an animated GIF of the actions you're talking about and posting the image. Super bonus upvotes for freehand circles in an animation.
- Create ASCII art blocks, leaving [numbered bullets between each step](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30046/how-do-i-include-a-code-block-right-after-a-list-without-it-turning-into-a-blockq/) so it's not all an entire block of `<pre></pre>`.
- Fumetti [the whole experience](http://alienlovespredator.com/2010/01/19/youre-so-white/).

Comment: +0.8 I like it all except the "Obfuscate the link" option.

Comment: Death to link squishifiers! @rob

Comment: Atwood used the obfuscate link option to go to LMGTFY.

Answer (score 2):

`http://www.google.com/search?q=(YOUR QUERY)`
[Working Example](http://www.google.com/search?q=meta+stack+overflow+unicorns)